# Mostrar nombre de la persona que se encuentra conectada al sistema

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de sanciones militares desde cero. con PHP y MYSQL

Ya instale el sistema de LOGIN de usuario

Mi duda es:

Como logro mostrar un mensaje de bienvenido con el nombre del usuario que se conecto?

ME SALE EL SIGUIENTE ERROR:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for bd_usuario(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\home.php on line 24 and defined
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\funciones.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de
>   Sanciones\funciones.php on line 10

Uso los siguientes formularios:

FORMULARIO LOGIN:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Login</h2>

    <form role="form" name="login" action="php/login.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Nombre de usuario o email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Acceder</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <script src="js/valida_login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FUNCION DE LOGEO:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_POST["username"]) &&isset($_POST["password"])){
    if($_POST["username"]!=""&&$_POST["password"]!=""){
        include "conexion.php";

        $user_id=null;
        $sql1= "select * from user where (username=\"$_POST[username]\" or email=\"$_POST[username]\") and password=\"$_POST[password]\" ";
        $query = $con->query($sql1);
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $user_id=$r["id"];
            break;
        }
        if($user_id==null){
            print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido.\");window.location='../login.php';</script>";
        }else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user_id"]=$user_id;
            print "<script>window.location='../home.php';</script>";                
        }
    }
}
}

?>
```

FUNCION DE MOSTRAR NOMBRE DE USUARIO:

```
function bd_usuario($user_id)
{
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM user WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
return $sql;
}
```

FORMULARIO DE BIENVENIDA CUANDO SE CONECTA EL USUARIO:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
    print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='login.php';     </script>";
}
$user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];

?>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<?php include "funciones.php"; ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>.: HOME :.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
<?php
$usuario = bd_usuario();
echo "";
?>
</div>
</div>
<    /div>
</body>
</html>
```

MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA

Answer (score 1):

En la llamada a la funcion en la pagina home.php no estas incluyendo el atributo user_id, debes pasarlo como argumento.

Prueba poniendo el siguiente codigo dentro de la funcion `bd_usuario`:

```
include "conexion.php";

$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM user WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
$fullname = null;

$query = $con->query($sql);
while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
    $fullname=$r["fullname"];
    break;
}

return $fullname;
```

Comment: ya no da el error, pero me pasa es esto:

SELECT fullname FROM user WHERE id = '1' LIMIT 1

Comment: Mira la función en ese caso debes ejecutar el SQL:
     
`$query = $con->query($sql);
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $user_id=$r["id"];
            break;
        }`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\funciones.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\funciones.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\home.php(24): bd_usuario('1') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de Sanciones\funciones.php on line 11

me da ese error si la pego dentro de la funcion

Comment: Hola @AndresSanchez. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte! ¿Podrías mostrar con un poco más de detalle cómo estarías respondiendo a la pregunta? Quizás convendría detallar un poco los motivos y mostrar el código en tu respuesta (siguiendo lo que se explica en [answer]). La idea es sumar respuestas con la mayor calidad posible en el sitio.

Comment: @VictorAlejandroAlvaradoVilo - Supongo que `$user_id` son números enteros... quita las comillas simple en la query... `id = $user_id`